# Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed while I'm trying to display the GUI of sikulix running ubuntu inside a docker container

Tags: docker, ubuntu, permissions, sikuli, xorg

I'm tryng to display the GUI of sikulix using a docker container. Below you can see my Dockerfile :

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04
ENV HOME /home/developer
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
ENV LC_ALL C.UTF-8
ENV LANG C.UTF-8
ENV VIRTUAL_ENV=/protected-env
ENV PATH "/home/developer:/protected-env/bin:/bin:/bin/2.82/python/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin"
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y curl apt-utils wget libopenexr-dev bzip2 build-essential zlib1g-dev libxmu-dev libxi-dev libxxf86vm-dev libfontconfig1 libxrender1 libgl1-mesa-glx xz-utils firefox default-jdk python3-numpy xvfb
# Replace 1000 with your user / group id
RUN export uid=1000 gid=1000 && \
    mkdir -p /home/developer && \
    echo "developer:x:${uid}:${gid}:Developer,,,:/home/developer:/bin/bash" >> /etc/passwd && \
    echo "developer:x:${uid}:" >> /etc/group && \
    echo "developer ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL" > /etc/sudoers.d && \
    chmod 0440 /etc/sudoers.d && \
    chown ${uid}:${gid} -R /home/developer
#RUN chmod ugo+rwx /home/developer
USER developer
RUN echo "Download and install SikuliX"
RUN curl -L https://launchpad.net/.../+download/sikulixide-2.0.5.jar -o /home/developer/sikulixide-2.0.5.jar
CMD java -jar /home/developer/sikulixide-2.0.5.jar
#CMD /usr/bin/firefox
#RUN /usr/bin/firefox
# Set the working directory
WORKDIR /
```

This is the script that should display the sikulix ide :

```
docker run -ti --rm \
       -e DISPLAY=$DISPLAY \
       -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix \
        java -jar /home/developer/sikulixide-2.0.5.jar
```

Something is broken,because I get this error :

**docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:367: starting container process caused: exec: "-jar": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown.**

Comment: Is there an image name before `java`?  The `docker run` command as you've shown it runs [the Docker Hub `java` image](https://hub.docker.com/_/java) passing `-jar ...` as the command to run.

Comment: thanks. I've fixed the start.sh script like this : docker run -ti --rm \
           -e DISPLAY=$DISPLAY \
           -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix \
             sikuli/cont
it works,the gui of sikulix appears ,but I see this error : [error] FileManager: writeStringToFile: did not work: /home/developer-sikulix/.Sikulix/SikulixStore/lastUsedJar.txt
/home/developer-sikulix/.Sikulix/SikulixStore/lastUsedJar.txt (No such file or directory)